# Rotate squares on mouse hover JavaScript

Tags: html, css, rotation

I need to reposition the 5 squares in this HTML code via `init()`
function and the `reposition()` function.
I looked on the other
HTML/CSS subjects of the website, but I didn't not find anything
helpful for this information.
Here are the questions :

> A. Add in the `init()` function the code required for the
> `reposition()` function to be called as soon as you hover over an
> element of the page associated  with the CSS class "square".
>
> B. Modify the "reposition" function so that it allows you to
> reposition the square in symmetry with respect to the diagonal.To do
> this, simply reverse the horizontal and vertical positions of this
> square.

Note : the pink square will not move because it is precisely on the diagonal (identical horizontal and vertical positions).

And here is my starting code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr"
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reposition the squares</title>
    <style>
        #bac {
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .square {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        #carre1 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 300px;
            top: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #carre2 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 120px;
            top: 75px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        #carre3 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            top: 240px;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        #carre4 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 350px;
            top: 0px;
            background-color: black;
        }
        #carre5 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            top: 50px;
            background-color: pink;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function init() {
        }
        function reposition() {
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <h1>Reposition the squares</h1>
    <div id="bac">
        <div id="carre1" class="square"></div>
        <div id="carre2" class="square"></div>
        <div id="carre3" class="square"></div>
        <div id="carre4" class="square"></div>
        <div id="carre5" class="square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how to add an event listener?

Comment: Yes, a bit, but I don't know how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can go about this. I'm assuming you want one square to rotate when you hover over it, so, you can do this with CSS styles. Just how you would style a div or any other HTML element, you can for example, make everything with the `.square` class rotate on mouse hover like so:

```
.square:hover {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

If you want to smooth this out, add `transition: 0.5s;` to your `.square` selector.

If you want to do the same thing in JavaScript, make sure you add that transition I was just talking about, then you can pick out a specific square to rotate by it's id like so:

```
document.getElementById("carre1").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    document.getElementById("carre1").style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
});
```

This essentially does the same thing but doesn't revert the square when your mouse leaves the square.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you very much, that solves it ! Have a good evening